# Selecting Leaderboard Using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

Ok I have a table with the following fields:

correct_id, player_id, reward

I want to create a list in descending order of who has had the most correct answers, how many questions they got right and what was the total reward they earned. How do I do it?

```
SELECT player_id, sum(correct_id), sum(reward) FROM questions_correct GROUP BY count(correct_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT player_id, COUNT(correct_id) CorrectAnsCnt, SUM(correct_id), SUM(reward) 
FROM questions_correct 
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY CorrectAnsCnt DESC
```